# saving the results of a mysql query into a session variable array not producing the expected results

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking to do the following:

- Have a search form on my main page which allows me to search a database of customers for their first name. Then have a combo box created containing the results.

I have the following php file. search.php which contains the code for querying the database and saving it into a session array.

```
<?php
include 'newCustomer.php';
connect('final');


    $query = $_POST['searchDB']; 
    $query = htmlspecialchars($query); // stop HTML characters
    $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query); //stop SQL injection
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE First_Name LIKE '$query'") ;//query the DB with search field in colleumn selected//



    if($data === FALSE) {
    $error = 'Query error:'.mysql_error();
    echo $error;
    }
    else
    {
    $test = array();
    $colNames = array();
    while($results = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)){// puts data from database into array, loops until no more

    $test[] = $results;

        }
         $anymatches = mysql_num_rows($data); //checks if the querys returned any results
        if ($anymatches != 0) {
        $_SESSION['names']=$test;

    $colNames = array_keys(reset($test));


    }

            if ($anymatches == 0) 
                    { 
                        echo "Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your query<br><br>"; 
                    } 

    } 

//header("location: newCustomer.php");
//die
?>
```

and the folling code in my main page which uses the array to create a combo box of names.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['names'])){
echo "Customers";
$array1 = $_SESSION['names'];
echo'<select name="customers>';
foreach($array1 as $name){
echo'<option value="'.$name["First_Name"].'">'.$name["First_Name"].'</option>';
}
echo'</select>';


}

?>
```

Once the form contaning the search parameters is submitted the search.php action is performed.

My database has the following names.

Dan Smith
Dan Tom
Dan Dan
Jim Smith
Jim Tom 
Jim Jim.

However when i search for dan, the combo box is created with Dan repeated 24 times
when i search for Jim its created with Jim listed twice...  why is it  producing such seemingly random results?

thanks,

Comment: Well its because everytime you search you are only returning back the values of what was searched for, and setting that into $_SESSION['names'], you need to do a SELECT * on all and store that into a SESSION variable, then do your search...

Comment: Nevermind, I think I misunderstood you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, and kindly meant, this code is going nowhere and will not get you what you want in the end.  My advice is to start over.

I think what you want is to be able to select the user from the combobox.  If so, you'd do well to try it slightly differently.

There are actually several ways of making this happen:

1. Use POST to send the search term to a script which then renders the whole next page.
2. Use AJAX to create a new combobox without rendering the whole page.
3. Use AJAX to create a Google Suggest style dropdown box.
4. Your way.

Method 3 is covered in the excellent AJAX tutorial on w3schools.com and would be the best way to achieve what you need.

As you have used something similar to method 1, the following code will produce a suitable dropdown.  Please note the use of mysqli_* as a better alternative to the deprecated mysql_*:

```
$searchtext=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqlidb,$_POST['searchDB'];
$sql="SELECT userid,forename,surname FROM users WHERE forename LIKE '%$searchtext%'";
$result=$mysqlidb->query($sql);
$combo="<SELECT name='customers'>";//note you had an error in your quotes on yours
while($row=$result->fetch_asssoc())
    {
    $combo.=sprintf("<OPTION value='%s'>%s %s</OPTION>",$row['userid'],$row['forename'],$row['surname']);
    }
echo $combo;
```

This should return you a $_POST['customers'] which contains the userid of the customer.  Your method would return the first name, which may mean you select the wrong customer.

In a secure envirnoment, you would also want to obfuscate the user id as it is poor practice to expose the key to a table like this, but as long as you recognise this fact for the future, I'd begin by using the code as wrote - easier to debug till you are confident.

You can also use this code to produce the required dropdown for method 2, though in reality, that is probably best kept for where a second combobox needs to change depending on the user's selection of a first.

If you still get duplicate names, you may find it worthwhile trying var_dump($test); to see if your table has a bit more in it than you thought...

If this answer is good, please don't forget to select it as it helps others to see what worked and what did not.  If it doesn't work, please add a comment for the same reason.

Comment: I couldn't get this code to run - but decided on method 3. You were right about the database having more than I thought though. I created a new test database and it worked fine.